# Pseudocode: Input 3 Integers, Multiply Largest 2

Tags: algorithm, if-statement, pseudocode

This is my first question so I apologize for any errors in advance.

In my algorithm development class we just learned IF ELSE statements, and i've been tasked with writing the pseudocode for a program that will input 3 numbers, decide which two are the largest, and then multiply those two. I've read most answers to questions like these but none of them use only IF ELSE statements, could anyone help me with the pseudocode for this problem?

Comment: "only IF ELSE statements", what exactly does that mean? literally nothing else?

Comment: You need to have at least *some* idea how this is supposed to work. Give some general outline and show us. That should be fairly straightforward with pseudocode. If you then have a *specific* question, ask here. If you have problems with the pseudocode, tell us exactly what problem you have. As of now, your question is just too broad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Multiplying the two largest numbers**

Let's assume that we have three integers namely `X` , `Y` and `Z`

We are going to read from keyboard the values of those integer

```
X = INPUT
Y = INPUT
Z = INPUT
```

The next step is to figure out the two largest number :

There so many approaches for finding the solution to this problem:

```
if (Y >= X) and (X >= Z)
   result = Y * X
else if (Y <= Z) and (Y <= X)
   result = X * Z
else
   result = Z * Y
```

the variable `result` CONTAIN the multiplication of two largest number.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you so much

Answer (score -1):

```
a =input
b=input
c=input
if a<=b and a<=c:
      print b*c
else if b<=c and b<=a:
      print a*c
else:
     print a*b
```

Comment: This code seems, frankly, terrible. Why not determine the two maximum numbers and *then* multiply those? Much more straightforward, easier to read, easier to implement... just everything. The OP didn't mention printing at all, by the way. Besides, you didn't even explain anything in your answer, just dump pseudocode on the OP. The OP learns nothing from that.